# How to decrement only non-zero elements of a matrix without using a loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there an easy way to decrement only non-zero elements of a matrix without using a loop? Here is how I do it using a loop:

```
NAV = [5 0 8 4 3 0 0];
for i = 1:length(NAV)
    if NAV(i)> 0
       NAV(i) = NAV(i)-1;
    end
end
```

But I am looking for one liner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the non-zero elements, subtract 1 and replace them at their indices

```
NAV(NAV~=0) = NAV(NAV~=0)-1;
```

Your code, by the way, doesn't do what you have asked. Your code decrements positive elements; not non-zero elements.

Vectorised version of your loop is:

```
NAV(NAV>0) = NAV(NAV>0)-1;
```